# Dropdown closes when link inside is clicked

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I am working on dropdown menu triggered by click. The problem I have is when I click on the link in already opened dropdown, the dropdown it self closes. I am trying to queue the state with setTimeout and clearTimeOut: when the link is clicked in the `dropdownBox`, setTimeOut on the `dropdownBox` should be cleared by function `clickitem`, and therefore dropdown shouldn't close. But here I am failing. Could someone suggest me how can I make this work? Btw I can't use jquery, only Javascript.

```
const trigger = document.querySelector('.ul-catalogue > li > a');
const dropdownBox = document.querySelector('.nav > .ul-catalogue > li > .dropdown');
const link = document.querySelector(".dropdown > ul > li");

function handleClick() {
    dropdownBox.classList.add('trigger-click');
    setTimeout(() => dropdownBox.classList.add('trigger-click-active'), 150);
  dropdownBox.focus();
}

var timeOut;
function handleClickOut() {
    timeOut = setTimeout(() => dropdownBox.classList.remove('trigger-click', 'trigger-click-active'), 0);
}

function clickitem() {
clearTimeout(timeOut);
}  

trigger.addEventListener('click', handleClick);//This we do not touch
dropdownBox.addEventListener('blur', handleClickOut, true);
link.addEventListener('click', clickitem);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zw9w8eg0/3/

Comment: Why do you use the function handleClickOut()?

Comment: handleClickOut() is needed to close the dropdown, if user clicks outside dropdown area.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `link` has `href="#"`, so when you click it, you are redirecting to the same page, but all your updates will be reset to their original state.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved it:
I need to listen when dialog is on focusin (It is on focusin when user is fx. clicking on the links). So i added `dropdownBox.addEventListener('focusin', clickitem, true);` Full code:

```
    const trigger = document.querySelector('.ul-catalogue > li > a');
const dropdownBox = document.querySelector('.nav > .ul-catalogue > li > .dropdown');

function handleClick() {
    dropdownBox.classList.add('trigger-click');
    setTimeout(
        () => dropdownBox.classList.add('trigger-click-active'), 0);
  dropdownBox.focus();
}

var timeOut;

function handleClickOut() {
    timeOut = setTimeout(() => this.classList.remove('trigger-click', 'trigger-click-active'), 0);
}

    function clickitem() {
        clearTimeout(timeOut);
} 


trigger.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
dropdownBox.addEventListener('focusout', handleClickOut, true);
dropdownBox.addEventListener('focusin', clickitem, true);
```